# How to do "is_natural_no_zero" and "not required" in form validation?

Tags: codeigniter

Apparently in CodeIgniter this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('type', 'Type', 'trim|is_natural_no_zero|max_length[11]');
```

is the same as this in terms of required:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('type', 'Type', 'trim|required|is_natural_no_zero|max_length[11]');
```

they both return false if the post was like so:

```
[type] => ''
```

Whats i am trying to do is set the data as **is_natural_no_zero** but only if the data is not empty. Is there a solution to this using regular CodeIgniter validation? if not I will have to use [Callbacks](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to work around it and this is what i have done:

```
if (strlen($this->input->post('type'))) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('type', 'Type', 'trim|is_natural_no_zero|max_length[11]');
}
```